# How to execute 0 when printing out the loop? I've been trying to print out the factorial in python. I need 0 to be printed in the output

Tags: python, loops, factorial

```
    def fact(n):
        f=1
        for num in range(1,n+1):
            if num==0:
                return 1
            else:
                f=f*num
                print(num,f) 
    n=int(input())
```

```
fact(n)
#here is my code, but the output should be 
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 6
4 24
5 120
6 720
instead of 
1 1
2 2
3 6
4 24
5 120
6 720
```

Can you tell me what is wrong and what should I add to the code?

Comment: Also, I've tried and It is not working when I write it just as for num in range(n).

Comment: `num in range(1, n+1)`  well... `num` can never be `0` with that range, and `f=1`... so there will never be any zeroes

Comment: Thank you everyone!!! I just added print(0,0) and now it says that the code is correct. Didn't expect that it would be a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0, 0 can't really be part of the factorial because then all following numbers would have to be multiplied by 0, making them all zero. I guess you could just print it out first.

```
def fact(n):
    f=1
    print(0, 0)
    for num in range(1,n+1):
        
        f=f*num
        print(num,f) 
n=int(input())
fact(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking for granted that 0! = 1 and 1! = 1, then you already have the two first numbers of your sequence. So you can multiply by `num+1` to avoid multiplying by zero. Then you take your output before doing the next multiplication.

```
def fact(n):
    f=1
    for num in range(n+1):
        print(num,f)
        f=f*(num+1)
```

```
fact(5)
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 6
4 24
5 120
```

You can also create a lookup table if you want:

```
def fact(n):
    FACT=[]
    f=1
    for num in range(n+1):
        FACT += [f]
        f=f*(num+1)
    return FACT

F = fact(n)

F[0]
>>> 1

F[4]
>>> 24
```

Answer (score 0):

- `range` should start from `0`, hence `range(0, n+1)` or just `range(n+1)` because in your code the condition is never hit
- when the condition is hit you should have a `print`: `print(0, 0)`

```
def fact(n):
    f=1
    for num in range(0,n+1):
        if num==0:
            print(num, num) # num is just 0
        else:
            f=f*num
            print(num,f)
```

Remarks:

- the `return` is really needed? it is always `1` independently from `n`
- 0! = 1 by definition. Maybe `print(0, 1)`?

Comment: Nope, I sent my code to our schools online judge system but its says the output is wrong, because first line should be 0 0(( and print out the code only using (num,result)

Comment: @Zhanylmyrza Askarova edited, removed the `return`